# Find diameter of partially filled cone

Tags: geometry

So I am trying to work out a formula for the diameter of a partially filled cone with a non-zero diameter. For example, if I were filling a cup with water and I know the diameter of the bottom of the cup and either the volume of liquid I am pouring or the height of the liquid once it is poured, how can I calculate the diameter at the top of the water line?

I have been trying to use the formulas from [here](https://www.lmnoeng.com/Volume/CylConeSphere.php) but I don't seem to be able to work out the formulas properly. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyLgd.png) is an image to help with what I am trying to accomplish. I have D(bottom) and h and the slope of the wall, but I need D(top)

Comment: You need more information. What you have it does not uniquely describe a cone. Do you have the diameter at the top?

Comment: No top diameter, only the bottom. essentially the question is if i took a cup and i know the diameter of the bottom of the cup and i pour in a certain volume, can i know the top diameter of the liquid once it has been filled?

Comment: Please see edit too!

Comment: So you have the slope of the wall? Like an angle?  Can you put it on the plot?

Comment: The formula for this specific situation would be y = 14x

Comment: I still don't have enough information. It depends on the slope of the wall. Different slope, will give different diameters at the same height. You can calculate that, but you need more knowledge. Bottom diameter, height, and volume would be enough. Or bottom diameter, height, and slope

Comment: i have all of those things. i am looking for a formula that would describe the top diameter in terms of those things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the total volume and the height, you can use the formula for the cone:
$$V=\frac{\pi h}{12}(D_{top}^2+D_{top}D_{bottom}+D_{bottom}^2)$$
You can rewrite this as:
$$D_{top}^2+D_{top}D_{bottom}+D_{bottom}^2-\frac{12V}{\pi h}=0$$
Just apply the formula for quadratic, and choose the solution with $D_{top}\ge D_{bottom}$.

If you know the slope (let's call the angle $\alpha$), then $$\tan \alpha=\frac{R_{top}-R_{bottom}}{h}$$